# How to randomize the location of a button in kivy python screen manager?

Tags: python, button, kivy, screen

I'm a newbie when it comes to python and kivy, and I have been working on this problem for a while and getting nowhere, so any help is greatly appreciated.  I am working on a behavioral task for rats, in which they would need to press a white square button on a screen to get a treat.  I want the white square to appear in one of three locations each time the stimulus screen appears.  Here is the relevant code that I have so far:

main.kv:

```
<Stimulus>:
    on_pre_enter: self.update_pos()
    FloatLayout:
        StimButton:
            id: stimbutton
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'screen1'

<StimButton>
    background_normal: ''
    color: 1,1,1,1
    size_hint: 0.2, 0.3
```

and within the python main.py:

```
class Stimulus(Screen):
    a = ObjectProperty(None)
    def update_pos(self):
        b = randint(1,3)
        if b==1:
            a = {'x':0.1,'y':0.33}
        elif b==2:
            a = {'x':0.4,'y':0.33}
        elif b==3:
            a = {'x':0.7,'y':0.33}
        self.ids.stimbutton.pos_hint = a

class StimButton(Button):
    def on_press(self):
        deliver_pellet()
```

What should happen is that a white square appears, when the rat presses it they get a treat and it switches to a dark screen.  After a delay, a white square shows up in a different one of the 3 possible locations, and they go again.  What ends up happening is that I get one white square in the lower left corner, and the next time the screen appears I have a square in one of the random 3 positions, and one in the lower left corner.  Pressing either square produces the desired outcome.  How do I get that square in the lower left to go away?

Answer (score 0):

You don´t show how you implement the `screen1` class, however it seems as if you create another instance of your button.

A simple and reproducible example based on your code would be:

**main.kv:**

```
<ScreenManagement>:
    Stimulus:
    BlackScreen:

<BlackScreen>
    name: "black_screen"
    on_pre_enter: self._sleep()

<Stimulus>:
    name: "stimulus_screen"
    stimButton_pos: self._random_pos()
    on_pre_enter: self._update_pos()

    FloatLayout:
        StimButton:
            id: stimbutton
            pos_hint: root.stimButton_pos
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'black_screen'

<StimButton>
    background_normal: ''
    color: 1,1,1,1
    size_hint: 0.2, 0.3
```

**main.py:**

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.5')

import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


class BlackScreen(Screen):
    def _sleep(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self._change_screen, 3)

    def _change_screen(self,  dt):
        self.manager.current = "stimulus_screen"


class Stimulus(Screen):
    stimButton_pos = ObjectProperty(None)

    def _update_pos(self):
        self.stimButton_pos = self._random_pos()

    def _random_pos(self):
        pos = random.choice(({'x':0.1,'y':0.33},
                             {'x':0.4,'y':0.33},
                             {'x':0.7,'y':0.33}))

        return pos


class StimButton(Button):
    def on_press(self):
        #deliver_pellet()
        pass


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ScreenManagement()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

I use `kivy.clock.Clock.schedule_once` to provide a delay of 3 seconds between screens.

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the explanations and complete example for details.

## #1. Add a method into Python script

We will add a method, "display_stimulus_screen" into the Stimulus class. This method will be schedule once when the rat pressed the stimulus button.

```
class Stimulus(Screen):
...
    # dt means delta time
    def display_stimulus_screen(self, dt):
        self.manager.current = "stimulus"
```

## #2. Add id and screen names into kv File

We will give an id to the Stimulus screen so that we can reference the new method that we just added in the Python script.

```
<ScreenManagement>:
    Stimulus:
        id: stimulus
        name: "stimulus"
    Screen1:
        name: "screen1"
```

## #3. Create a delay

We will import Kivy Clock and use Clock.schedule_once method to invoke the new method called "display_stimulus_screen" with a specific time interval. In this example we use 0.5 seconds. The following is added to the kv file.

```
#:import Clock kivy.clock.Clock
...
            on_press:
                root.manager.current = 'screen1'    # display black screen
                Clock.schedule_once(root.manager.ids.stimulus.display_stimulus_screen, 0.5)
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

from random import randint


def deliver_pellet():
    print("deliver pellet")


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


class Screen1(Screen):
    pass


class Stimulus(Screen):
    a = ObjectProperty(None)

    def update_pos(self):
        b = randint(1, 3)
        if b == 1:
            a = {'x': 0.1, 'y': 0.33}
        elif b == 2:
            a = {'x': 0.4, 'y': 0.33}
        elif b == 3:
            a = {'x': 0.7, 'y': 0.33}
        self.ids.stimbutton.pos_hint = a

    # dt means delta time
    def display_stimulus_screen(self, dt):
        self.manager.current = "stimulus"   # name of Stimulus Screen


class StimButton(Button):
    def on_press(self):
        deliver_pellet()


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ScreenManagement()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0
#:import Clock kivy.clock.Clock

<ScreenManagement>:
    Stimulus:
        id: stimulus
        name: "stimulus"
    Screen1:
        name: "screen1"

<Screen1>:


<Stimulus>:
    on_pre_enter: self.update_pos()

    FloatLayout:
        StimButton:
            id: stimbutton
            on_press:
                root.manager.current = 'screen1'    # display black screen
                Clock.schedule_once(root.manager.ids.stimulus.display_stimulus_screen, 0.5)

<StimButton>
    background_normal: ''
    color: 1,1,1,1
    size_hint: 0.2, 0.3
```